# Изменить текст ребенка у префаба в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, текст

Есть префаб у которого есть ребенок `TextMeshPro`.
Как мне получить доступ к этому ребенку чтобы я мог изменять текст?
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class TankEnd : MonoBehaviour
{
    GroundSpawner groundSpawner;
    public TextMeshProUGUI levelText;

    public int level; 

    void Start()
    {
        groundSpawner = GameObject.Find("GroundSpawner").GetComponent<GroundSpawner>();
        level = groundSpawner.level;
        levelText.text = "Level " + level;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ответ ниже устроил и вопрос решен ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Получаете ребенка;
2. Работаете с компонентом.

Общий код:

```
GameObject mychild = originalGameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;    
mychild.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text = "" + currentResult;
```

Comment: Второй раз натыкаюсь на твои ответы и как-то больно становится... а что случится если в иерархии объект с текстом будет не первый под родителем? заходить переписывать код каждый раз? И зачем здесь конкатенация с пустым стрингом? это новый метод каста?

Comment: Ответ дан для понимания принципа работы. Дальше сам должен адаптировать под свои нужды.